# Data Structure to compare coordniates in a huge square board (1000 x 1000)

Tags: java, algorithm

I am designing a board game which is of `(1000 x 1000)`. The board is filled with unique numbers. I call a random number generator which compares the number generated to the one on the board and crosses the number out on the board. Now every time this happens, I have to check if the entire row/column/diagonal has been crossed out and if yes I have to proceed to something else.

Rather than iterating every single time after a number has been called to check the row/column/diagonal is there a way of caching the already checked ones so that I don't have to repeat some iterations?

Comment: The only solutions I can think of are significantly more complicated than what you're already doing.  Avoid premature optimization; stick with the simple solution you already have.

Comment: 1000 x 1000 is only 1M numbers. Assuming 4-byte ints, we are only talking 4MB of data. Pretty small when you consider photo, audio, video processing.

Comment: The thing is I want to increase the size to `10000 x 10000` once I create a working solution.

Comment: but why do you think four simple loops over 10000 elements is slow?  10000 operations at 1GHz takes ~10 microseconds. i would worry more about keeping the board sufficiently compact that it can all fit in the cpu's cache.  that will affect your speed much more than tweaking algorithms for what are fast (O(n)) operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got this right, it's some sort of Bingo-like game.

Reading above, having an iterator to reach 1000 would be the solution if you needed just to check for rows, or columns.

But since you need to check for diagonals too you can't just increase an iterator.
I.E: A diagonal could contain just 3 numbers and be crossed out with those 3, not 1000.

You could use an algorithm that will let you know, for any position you pass, what is its row, column and diagonal.

If all those values are true, you canceled out the whole row/column diagonal.
You have a fixed 1000x1000 matrix, so (int)(CalledNumber/1000)-1 is the row to check, (CalledNumber%1000) is the column.
To get the diagonal you'll subtract a column for each row you go up, and add 1 column for each row you go down when going from left to right, and the reverse operation when going from right to left.

Since that would be a boolean[1000][1000] matrix, once you gather all the positions you need, just check those together with an AND condition, if it's true the whole row/diagonal/column is crossed out.

That way you will just need to retrieve the positions that are relevant for each number and checking with boolean should be fast enough and wouldn't require much memory.

Edit: the other possibile way is already posted: precalculate every diagonal/row columnd and decrease some counters, but I find that a bit of a waste of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. But since 1000 isn't *that* big a number, you may well find it isn't necessary unless you're doing it a *lot.* My advice is to start with what you have and only introduce this  *if* you strike a definite problem.

The idea I have is to simply keep a count of the number of non-crossed-out numbers in each row, column and diagonal (I'll call these a collection from here on in). These are initialised to the maximum value for the collection and you just decrease the relevant ones whenever you cross out a cell (change from populated to crossed out).

Consider the following matrix:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

When you "cross out" `f`, you decrement the row counter for `def`, the column counter for `cfi` and the diagonal counters for `bf` and `hf`. The row and column indexes are easily calculable since they mirror exactly the information you already have (the row or column of the cell you're crossing out). Diagonal index is only *slightly* harder since it's a formula using *both* row and column.

Once you've identified the counters for a given cell and decremented them, simply check the counts against zero. Zero means all elements in the collection have been crossed out.

Comment: 1000 is not big. 1000*1000 = 1M which is kind of big.

Comment: @9000, yes but for a given cell, you don't have to process a million. There are only 1000 in the row, 1000 in the column and (at most) 1000 in each of the two diagonals. That's 4000, tops. Bigger than 1000, granted, but still nowhere near a mil.

Comment: How will you store the collections here? In your example you need more than 14 collections. Mine would need a lot more. Also, what will you use as a data structure? Would be helpful if you elucidate a little more. Also, my original aim is to have a `10000 x 10000` board after I get a solution for the above.

Comment: @noMAD, a simple array of integral types will do the trick (I'm not talking collections in the Java full-blown class sense of the word). The "hard" bit is simply figuring out how to work out the four indexes (row, column, diag1 and diag2) from the cell coordinates. The first two are easy, the diagonals are only a little harder, as stated.

Comment: In any case, my _first_ paragraph should be the one you're spending most effort reading. Only do this if it becomes necessary, otherwise YAGNI.

Answer (score 0):

While I really like the ideas of a simple counter for each column or row, you could also consider a BitSet as well.  The advantage is that, if you really need to, you can find out which cells are still there.  If this isn't useful, just use a counter.

Answer (score 0):

You might find an array or collection of [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)s helpful.